# Как добавить к цветному тексту TextView другой цветной текст?

Tags: java, android

Имеется следующий код:

```
Spannable sp = new SpannableString("Hello");
sp.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, sp.length(), 0);
textview.setText(sp, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Как к этому тексту в том же textview добавить еще несколько Spannable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно вас интересует метод [append](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))() у TextView.

Добавляем следующие три строки к уже имеющемуся коду:

```
Spannable spannableString= new SpannableString(" world");
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), 0, spannableString.length(), 0);
textview.append(spannableString);
```

На выходе получим TextView c текстом "Hello world", где "Hello" - красным, "world" - желтым.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, помогло.

Comment: @Кирилл да не за что.